# Error 1310 while Installing visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I am having the below error.
I had a licensed copy of Visual Studio and due to some problem I had to uninstall visual studio.
After that when I tried to reinstall a new copy of visual studio I am having problem as shown in attached image.
I had checked that, that file was not accessed by any of the process in the system.
When I manually tried to delete that file , still I couldn't do that , and the reason was that the file was corrupted or unreadable.

[image: Error While installing visual studio]

Please let me any solutions to this problem

Comment: do you have admin rights?

Comment: Yes I have the admin rights, but that file seems to be corrupted.

Comment: Solved the issue. Repaired C drive and the Corrupted file is gone.